# Providex ODBC CONCAT issue

Tags: sql, concatenation, odbc, providex

Accessing a database with Providex ODBC drivers.
Trying to Concatenate a String and Price value using the following in the Select statement.
Have tried any number of combinations to create a single value to display in an html template I don't control but need to provide for reporting.

```
SELECT
ItemCode,
{fn CONCAT('LIST PRICE',{fn CAST(StandardUnitPrice as varchar(10)) }) } as MSRP
FROM CI_Item
```

Probably ought to mention other scalar functions such as `{fn ROUND(StandardUnitPrice,2)}` also do not seem to work as expected based upon the documentation I found at
https://manual.pvxplus.com/PXPLUS/odbc/using_odbc_driver/scalar_functions.htm

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: It looks like this is MAS 90 4.0 ODBC driver and I am accessing it via the defined datasource dsn.  Sage\v2017\MAS90